# Use node script to start child process, capture child stdout, and kill child on close

Tags: node.js, npm, stdout, child-process

I would like to start a node-script called `myScript.js`, that starts a child process `npm start`, store the stdout of `npm start` into a global variable `let myVar`, and make sure that if the main program `myScript.js` is exited for any reason, the child process is killed as well. Nothing from the child's stdout should appear in the terminal window after ctr-c or similar.

---

My current solution does not kill on close:

```
const childProcess = require('child_process');

let myVar = ''

const child = childProcess.spawn('npm', ['start'], {
    detached: false
});

process.on('exit', function () {
    child.stdin.pause();
    child.kill();
});

child.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
    myVar = `${data}`
});
```

Can this be accomplished?

Comment: The link you provided leads to "Page not found".

Comment: Sorry, typing on my phone. Sharing the link as text: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25340875/nodejs-child-process-exec-disable-printing-of-stdout-on-console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Small change, but I think that might look something like this:

```js
const childProcess = require('child_process')

const child = childProcess.spawn('npm', ['start'], {shell:true});
var myVar = ''; child.stdout.setEncoding('utf8');
child.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
    myVar = data.toString(); 
});
child.on('close', function(exitcode) {
    // on the close of the child process, use standard output or maybe call a function
});

process.on('exit', function() {
    // I don't think pausing std.in is strictly necessary
    child.kill()
})
```

Further reading

- node's `child_process` documentation, [including event names](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#event-close)
- geeksforgeeks article on [child_process.spawn](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/node-js-child-process/)
- [This StackOverflow thread on getting and using the output of a child_process' pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14332721/node-js-spawn-child-process-and-get-terminal-output-live)
- [This StackOverflow thread on the difference between the `close` and `exit` events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37522010/difference-between-childprocess-close-exit-events)